# What can I pass the result of typeof(string) to a generic?

Tags: c#

What is wrong with this, and should I be doing to pass a type to a generic?

```
Type t = typeof(string);

var someThing = new SomeThing<t>(100);
```

Comment: Apologies in advance if I'm not giving you enough credit here, but are you simply asking how to instantiate a new generic ("SomeThing<T>") where T is a string?

Comment: the actual type is stored in the database, so I need to map that to a type in code.

Comment: Ok... just checking. :-) Thanks for clarifying.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to use reflection to do this:

```
var openType = typeof(SomeThing<>);
var constructedType = openType.MakeGenericType(new[] { typeof(string) });
var instance = Activator.CreateInstance(constructedType);
```

This won't be that useful though since you will not be able to use the type in a generic way but this approach can be helpful if you need to dynamically construct a generic type for an API call.

Answer (score 4):

Generic parameters must be known at compile time. That's how they ensure compile-time safety. In your case you have a dynamic type which is not known at compile time. The value of the `t` variable is only known at runtime. So you cannot use generics in this case.

You will have to use reflection if you have to work with runtime types.

Answer (score 1):

You should use the following code to construct a generic dynamically:

```
 Type generic = typeof(SomeThing<>); 
 Type[] typeArgs = { typeof(string) };

 Type constructed = generic.MakeGenericType(typeArgs);

 dynamic someThing = Activator.CreateInstance(constructed);
```

Answer (score 0):

Generic parameters need to be language types, not instances of class Type.

GetType() is a virtual function that returns an instance of class System.Type that can be used at runtime to obtain informations about a given type, but of course, we cannot use it as a generic parameter type.
Generics are in part handled in compile time and in part in run time, but they require to be used with language types.

Now, to solve your problem you have to change your strategy.
Usually you don't need to use too much both generics and reflection, by my experience, if you formulate your problem in a different way you can find a solution that uses only reflection, only inheritance, only generic or at least only generics and inheritance.

For example:

```
MyReturnType MyBestFunction<T>(.....)
{
    var someThing = new SomeThing<T>(100);
    ...
    ...
}

Then you can use your function passing the generic parameter.

var x = MyBestFunction<string>(....);
```